# How can i add fake audio video to conversation created by UCMA application

Tags: c#, ucma

I am running a sample of UCMA and would like to add Audio Video to the conversation , Can i add fake audio video to the call.

Any info / help would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a UserEndpoint, establish and then create AudioVideo call object, establish and add your UserEndpoint to the call.

If you have not succeeded, I can share sample source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCMA application calls can either be a [BackToBackCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.backtobackcall_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) or a [Call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.call_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx).

If you are talking about back to back calls, then no as you have no control over the media at all.

If you are talking about calls that terminate at the UCMA endpoint, then UCMA currently only supports audio, it does not support video.  So with audio the application is responsible about what audio to "[play](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn454813.aspx)" to the other side of the call.

Comment: Can i create a Video Conference in the case i would like to .. please le t me know

Comment: Yes, a UCMA application to connect into a conference call and to make the conference call to other participants.  Yes the conference call can have video.  But the UCMA endpoint in the conference call can't send or receive video stream(s) in the conference call.  The other non-UCMA participants can.

Comment: If you need to stream video you are two choices that I know of: 1. Use the Client SDK and control a single Lync Client endpoint.  This has downsides in that you have to "fake" a video source.  i.e. write a video camera driver and supply the video yourself.  2. Use a third party library that supports being a Lync sip endpoint with video.  I have seen these around but they cost a lot of memory in licensing fees.

Comment: Also the Lync Client SDK solution is not very scalable.

Comment: Thankyou Shane. I have added a conference call in UCMA. That suffices our requirement.